# how do I mock a class' dependency in jest

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

How would I mock a dependency of one of the classes I'm testing with jest?

I have a class that uses the `pigpio` module

```
// a trimmed down version of the class and method I'm writing a test for

import { Gpio } from "pigpio"

export default class BotController {

    private initializePenActuator(): void {
        this.penPause = Number(process.env.PEN_PAUSE_DELAY_IN_MILLISECONDS)
        this.penActuator = new Gpio(Number(process.env.PEN_ACTUATOR_PIN))
    }

    async setPenDirection(direction: penDirection, toggleAfterDelay?: boolean): Promise<void> {

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.penActuator.digitalWrite(direction) // the call I want to mock

            if (!toggleAfterDelay) {
                resolve()
            }

            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve()
            }, this.penPause)
        })
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to write the following test for it:

```
    test("can actuate with a delay", async () => {
        // * actuate pen with a delay
        const start: Date = new Date()

        await controller.setPenDirection(penDirection.UP, true)

        const end: Date = new Date()
        const duration = end.getTime() - start.getTime()

        // * confirm that the async call was delayed for the correct number of MS
        expect(duration).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(Number(process.env.PEN_PAUSE_DELAY_IN_MILLISECONDS))
    })
```

But I'm not sure how to write the mock for the pigpio method call for `digitalWrite`.

I know I can create a mock of a class:

```
jest.mock("pigpio", () => {
    return class {
        digitalWrite(value) {}
    }
})
```

But that would assume that I'm calling a pigpio class directly in the test, but not via a different class (right?).

I've been trying to read the docs on how to properly do this but I can't seem to parse the solution from the examples. If it's not obvious, I'm still green with testing.

How would I mock pigpio so that I can test my class' methods?

Also, if you have a link to the spot in the docs I should be looking at for this I would appreciate it. I don't know if I'm misunderstanding the docs I read or if I just didn't find the right place in the jest docs :|

## UPDATE

After looking through the automatic mock example from the docs pointed out by Estus I see the example of how to mock the class if the class is the default export of the module.

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#automatic-mock

But this example works if the class is the default export of the module. In my case the class isn't the default export:

[image: class to be mocked is not the default export]

And if I try to mock just the module I get an error:

[image: error when trying to mock the pigpio module]

If I try to mock the Gpio class for the module I still get the error:

[image: mocking just the gpio class, still erroring]

And I can't seem to find an example of properly doing this in the documentation :/

## ANOTHER UPDATE

I've also tried creating a mock function for the `Gpio` class, mocking the `pigpio` module and giving that mock an implementation that uses the `Gpio` mock and it still doesn't work:

[image]

Comment: *But that would assume that I'm calling a pigpio class directly in the test, but not via a different class* - no, it would make no sense to mock something you use directly in a test. jest.mock affects all modules that import pigpio in current test suite. Also see https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#automatic-mock

Comment: Ah!! I saw this example in the docs but didn't quite get the implementation (the variable names picked threw me), but looking at it now I get it. Thanks for the point to this part of the docs. Once I start working today I'll correct my spec and post the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @EstusFlask I tried implementing the example, but the docs are written for when the module's default export is the class you're trying to mock. I think this is where the docs threw me. I'm not sure how I would mock a class that's not the default export of the module. I updated my post with what I tried. Any thoughts?

Comment: You missed `__esModule: true` for jest.mock, you need it for named exports . Without it, a mock is treated as CommonJS module, which translates to ESM default export. See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options

Comment: :facepalm: oh man. Yeah that would have saved a day of debugging and head banging. I was reading through the jest docs but hadn't dove into the API at all yet. It seemed like a deeper dive than I thought I'd need when trying to learn jest. Thanks for the point. I'm updating my answer with the new info.

Comment: This is why people don't write tests ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soooooo,

I decided to go the dependency injection route. I really wanted to figured out how to mock the Gpio class without going the DI route just to figure it out, but at this point I just want to move foward.

## Dependency injection for a class constructor

So, dependency injection should be relatively easy right? Well, there's a bit of a snag with the dependency injection I was trying to do. I need to use the `Gpio` class **as a constructor**, not as an instance of Gpio.

In my `BotController` class I'm using the `Gpio` class to construct distinct instances of `Gpio`:

[image: gotta have a constructor]

But with typescript, if you inject a class into a constructor (and I assume methods), you don't get the class constructor, you get an instance of the class. To inject a constructor instead of an instance, you need to use `typeof`:

[image: storing the injected constructor]

Because [according to the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#constructor-functions):

> Here we use typeof Greeter, that is “give me the type of the Greeter class itself” rather than the instance type. Or, more precisely, “give me the type of the symbol called Greeter,” which is the type of the constructor function.

So now, I can mock the `pigpio` module and pass the mocked Gpio class in to be used as a constructor and the test does not blow up.

[image]

Tomorrow, moving forward!!!!

## Update

Have you ever scaled to the top of a mountain, stood on the peak tired but triumphant, and then looked down at the other side to see an escalator??

After posting this answer and going to bed I woke up to another super helpful comment from Estus:

> You missed __esModule: true for jest.mock, you need it for named exports . Without it, a mock is treated as CommonJS module, which translates to ESM default export. See jestjs.io/docs/en/…

I hadn't seen anything about this in the docs, but when you look at [the given section of the API reference](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options):

[image: facepalm]

So, with this new knowledge I was able to go back and change all of my BotController code back to it's original state, removing the dependency injection:

[image: constructor back to normal]

[image: actuator code back to normal]

And in my test I added the `__esModule: true` setting back into the mock's implementation, passed back my `Gpio` class mock with the `digitalWrite` mock and my test passes:

[image: test passes!]

I feel like I've been through the ringer, but in the end I'm happy to know several ways of tackling this problem. Hopefully the detail in this question and answer will save someone else the headache.

Comment: DI is absolutely redundant for mocking only purposes when you test with Jest.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for code